How can I use Events and Listeners in Laravel to send an email?
I'm developing a web application using Laravel and I want to use events and listeners to send an email. Specifically, I want to send a welcome email whenever a new user registers.
I know that Laravel has a built-in mechanism for handling events and listeners, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Could you please provide a detailed step-by-step guide on how to set up an event and listener for this purpose?
For example, I have a User model that handles new user registrations. How can I create an event for a new user registration and then set up a listener to send the welcome email?
Sample Code:
Here is my User model:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    // Model properties and other methods...
}

Specific Questions:

How do I define an event for new user registration?

How do I create a listener to send the welcome email?

How do I register this event and listener and use it in my application?


Any examples and detailed explanations that can help me accomplish this correctly would be greatly appreciated.

If you've tried Laravel Breeze then It has a real time example for Email verification using Listeners, Events and Notifications. Check EventServiceProvider.php it has One Event called Registered which is listened by SendEmailVerificationNotification class.

Which version of laravel you are using??

I believe what you want is already described in the documentation of Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#events . If you just want to listen when a new user is created you can use a closure, if you want to listen to multiple events of the User model then it would be better to use a Model Observer.
